# Log4j socketappender and ssl

Tags: java, log4j

i see that log4j2 have a simple approach to dealing with socketappenders that uses the SSL protocol.

But when I see log4j v1.2.17, I am disappointed to see that the nice amount of parameters that one could use in log4j2 to configure an ssl comm. were lacking in v1.

Is there are any way to make the socketAppender in v1.2.17  able to send data to a server over ssl port 443?

If this was not available in earlier log4j versions... How would one pass the logs to an external server securely? Is tweaking Nginx the only solution to wrap logs in ssl?